# I have filed my e returns before the due date but I mistakenly entered the DDO TAN number

Tags: income-tax, india

As I made a mistake in entering the wrong TAN number I have been charged a penalty (interest) and asked to pay the tax amount also.

Comment: @Brythan This is India.

Answer (score 1):

If you were served any notice, refute this and file an amended return correcting the TAN number. This will resolve the issue. You can file using Government Income Tax website.